# AttributeError at /Follow/ 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a function that list all the people who are following a particular user but I keep encountering this error which I can't seem to solve . Can someone give me a hand please :)

```
 error 

 AttributeError at /Follow/

 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/Follow/
 Django Version:    1.5.1
 Exception Type:    AttributeError
 Exception Value:   

 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
 Traceback:
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
   115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\endless_pagination\decorators.py" in decorated
   35.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 "C:\mysite\pet\views.py" in Followings
   97.     followers = Follow.objects.followers(user)

 Exception Type: AttributeError at /Follow/
 Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

models

```
 class Follow(models.Model):
     """ Model to represent Following relationships """
     follower = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='following')
     followee = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followers')
     created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

     objects = FollowingManager()

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = _('Following Relationship')
         verbose_name_plural = _('Following Relationships')
         unique_together = ('follower', 'followee')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return "User #%d follows #%d" % (self.follower_id, self.followee_id)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # Ensure users can't be friends with themselves
         if self.follower == self.followee:
        raise ValidationError("Users cannot follow themselves.")
         super(Follow, self).save(*args, **kwargs)




 class Person(models.Model):



     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

views

```
 @page_template('pagination.html')
 @login_required
 def Followings(request,template='following.html', extra_context=None):
     followers = Follow.objects.followers(user)
     person = Person.objects.filter(user__in=followers)
     context = {
        'page_template': 'pagination.html',
         'person' :Person.objects.filter(user__in=followers),

    }
     extra_context = {'person':person,}
     if extra_context is not None:
    context.update(extra_context)

     return render_to_response(
    template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

url

```
         url(
             r'^Follow/$',
             'pet.views.Followings',
             name= 'Followings',
         ),
```

Comment: What is `FollowingManager` ? Or you have any view function with name `Follow`?

Comment: @Rohan its here https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship/blob/master/friendship/models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
followers = Follow.objects.followers(user)
```

to

```
followers = request.user.followers.all()
```